# Dart - Functional Difference Between Conditional Operator vs. If Statement

Tags: dart, if-statement, conditional-operator

Why does this work:

```dart
var myAnimal = (1 == 1)? 'Cat' : 'Dog'; //OK
myList.forEach((element) => (1 == element)? print('1') : print('Not 1')); //OK
```

But this doesn't?

```dart
var myAnimal = if(1 == 1) 'Cat'; else 'Dog'; 
//Expected an identifier, but got 'if'
myList.forEach((element) => if(1 == element) print('1'); else print('Not 1')); 
//Expected an identifier, but got 'if'
```

I've been treating it like a given but I don't actually know why.

Comment: Terminlology nit: The Dart *conditional operator*, `?`/`:`, is one of *two* ternary operators in Dart. A ternary operator is one which takes three operands, like binary operator take two operands. The other ternary operator in Dart is `operator []=` (aka. index-set).

Answer (score 1):

Because one is a **statement** (`if`) and other is an **expression** (`ternary`).

A **statement** "does" something, while an **expression** evaluates to a value.

The `=>` in your function acts similarly to a `return` keyword.

While you can do something like: `return print('statement');` . You can't return two of those statements: `return: print('statement'); print('statement');`